# How do I prevent my phone from syncing contacts with Google with xPrivacy?

Tags: privacy, google-contacts

I have installed [xPrivacy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.bokhorst.xprivacy.installer) on my phone. Which rights for which app do I have to set?

Answer (score 3):

Why that complicated? There's no *Xprivacy* or other tool required to prevent your device from syncing contacts with Google. It's rather a question of your settings:

1. If on account creation you decided to "Backup your data with Google", you might want to re-consider this, as this might include more personal data than just your contacts
2. in *Settings→Accounts & Sync* you can define what should be synced with your online accounts (not restricted to Google). Switch off what you don't want to be synchronized.
3. in your contacts app, you can chose the "default storage". Using something other than "Google" here would also keep new entries from being sync'ed with Google. Note, however, that you cannot move existing entries between the several possible storages directly; you might need to export them, remove them, and (after switching your default storage) re-import them.

Btw: Same applies to your calendar. Except there I don't know of any export/import feature in the calendar app, so for this part you probably need a 3<sup>rd</sup> party app.

Comment: The first two points were exactly what I was doing, but still it "somehow" happened that all my contacts were synced into my Gmail Contacts nevertheless! So next time I want to be really sure that cannot happen again with the correct xPrivacy setting.

Comment: **+1** still for **option 3.**. I should do this before doing anything on my new phone